# Latex text on both sides

Tags: spacing

I don't wanna use 64x \space to achieve my goal. I was tryin to \begin{flushleft} and \begin{flushright} bo it attempts with new line. 
I wanna make something like this, where arrows shows distance between two words.

till now i had this, but it doesn't look good.

```
\begin{flushleft}
Date      \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space Signiture
\end{flushleft}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a number of suggestions in order to obtain fixed or rubber lengths between two words:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\newcommand{\clap}{\makebox[0pt]}

\begin{document}

X\dotfill X

Left \hspace*{200pt} Right

Left \hfill Right

\hspace*{40pt}Left \hfill Right

Left \hfill Right \hspace*{40pt}

\hfill Left \hfill Right \hspace*{\fill}

\hfill \clap{Left} \hfill \clap{Right} \hspace*{\fill}

\hfill $\frac{1}{3}$ \hfill $\frac{2}{3}$ \hspace*{\fill}

Left \hfill Middle \hfill Right

\leavevmode\rlap{Left} \hfill \clap{Middle} \hfill \llap{Right}

\hfill $\frac{1}{2}$ \hspace*{\fill}

\hfill \clap{Left} \hfill \hfill \clap{Right} \hspace*{\fill}

\hfill $\frac{1}{4}$ \hfill \hfill $\frac{3}{4}$ \hspace*{\fill}

\hfill \hfill \clap{Left} \hfill \hfill \hfill \clap{Right} \hfill \hspace*{\fill}

\hfill \hfill $\frac{2}{7}$ \hfill \hfill \hfill $\frac{5}{7}$ \hfill \hspace*{\fill}

\hspace{30pt} Left \hspace{50pt} Middle \hfill Right

Left \hfill Middle \hspace{40pt} Right \hspace*{25pt}

X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might mention that, when `\parindent` is not zero, `\noindent` can capture that for a single paragraph.